# xinitrc - set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

Tags: debian, environment-variables, d-bus, xinit

Not using display manager and executing startup logic via xinitrc.
Problem is some dbus-related env variables are not set.

xinitrc excerpt:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all  # note this errors
/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &

eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL GNOME_KEYRING_PID GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
```

First one returns error

> dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Invalid environment assignments

How to make sure dbus vars (eg `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`) are set?

Note alternatively I could comment out these lines from `/usr/bin/startx`:

```
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset SESSION_MANAGER
```

but not sure that's the way to go.

Running debian testing.

Comment: I usually run `xinit` directly on fedora without problems, so you are probably right that you need to stop `startx` from removing the dbus variable from the environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use `startx` just fine (Debian unstable + experimental). If you look at where the dbus environment variables are set (again), it's in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/20dbus_xdg-runtime`. I use my own `.xinitrc`, and I realized a bunch of problems I had stemmed from not sourcing the scripts in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` (as the default `xinitrc` does). Instead of trying to run `dbus-update-activation-environment` yourself, I would strongly recommend you source the files in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` instead (they add a bunch of other things like modifying your `xhost` settings).

Comment: Sourcing the system-wide `.d` dir is important since it contains a lot of useful defaults.